# Accessing nested css class from html template in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

How can I access a nested css class from my template ?

```
.class1{
***************************
.class2{
}
}
```

In my template I try to do the following:

```
<div [class.class1.class2] = "show === false">
```

But this does'not work. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: you can address the class directly. why nesting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use class1 and class2 in same element, then you dont have to nest the classes. Try below.

**SCSS**

```css
.class1{
   ***************************
   &.class2{
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div [ngClass] = "{ 'class1 class2': show === false}">
```